# Hibernate : @ValueGenerationType applied at insert but not update time

Tags: java, hibernate, azure

To have an update timestamp on my object, that is generated by the database rather than my Java program, I am using a custom annotation, marked with @ValueGenerationType, for which the generatedBy class has a ALWAYS GenerationTiming. My annotation and value generation class are nearly copies of the ones in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/generated/GeneratedValues.html) except that I tried to use

GenerationTiming.ALWAYS and not GenerationTiming.INSERT.
However, my timestamp appears to be created at insert time but never updated. When setting the hibernate.show_sql setting to true, I can see that current_timestamp is called on insert but not on update (the corresponding field is completely ignored in the generated sql for update).

I use a StatelessSession to do my insert/updates. When inserting, I have to manually refresh to see the timestamp on my object, but when updating, any number of refreshes won't change the fact that the timestamp is not updated.
Am I missing something about the meaning of GenerationTiming.ALWAYS ? Is there something more on top of the custom annotation to add to my field to get it to be updated?

NB: The problem is the same using versions **4.3.11** or **5.1.0** of Hibernate. I connect to a Microsoft Azure SQL database using SQLServer2012Dialect.

**Code samples :**
my persisted object contains a timestamp field :

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@InDatabaseTimestamp
protected Date date;
```

my InDatabaseTimestamp annotation :

```
@ValueGenerationType(generatedBy = InDatabaseTimestampGeneration.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InDatabaseTimestamp {}
```

my InDatabaseTimestampGeneration class :

```
public class InDatabaseTimestampGeneration implements AnnotationValueGeneration<InDatabaseTimestamp> {

  @Override
  public GenerationTiming getGenerationTiming() {
    return GenerationTiming.ALWAYS;
  }

  @Override
  public ValueGenerator<?> getValueGenerator() {
    // no in-memory generation
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean referenceColumnInSql() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public String getDatabaseGeneratedReferencedColumnValue() {
    return "current_timestamp";
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(InDatabaseTimestamp annotation, Class<?> propertyType) {
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem and I think that this is an Hibernate Bug.
I checking the code for the class org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister and I can see that the logic to include de string in the insert statement is there, but it is not there for the update stament.
Maybe it is necesary to report this and try to modify the hibernate code

Comment: @Pablo Perich says, "facing exactly the same problem and I think that this is a Hibernate Bug. I checked the code for the class `org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister` and I can see that the logic to include the string in the insert statement is there, but it is not there for the update statement. Maybe it is necessary to report this and try to modify the hibernate code"

Answer (score -3):

It seems that you can try to annotate your property `date` as below.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS) 
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Date date;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I cannot use this, since I need to provide my own annotation (how would hibernate guess which way I want to generate the timestamp?) If I leave my annotation, there is a conflict org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Only one generator annotation is allowed

Comment: This answer does not deal with what question asks at all

Comment: @MichaelGantman, you found solution for this? I am still struggling with it

Comment: @Mayuran - tried and tried to find hibernate solution for this. They have Solutions provided in hibernate documentation but none of them worked. I ended up creating on-create and  on-update trigger in DB on needed fields in addition to hibernate annotations. And that worked for me

Comment: @MichaelGantman, its sad that hibernate doesn't provide a way to generate database CURRENT_TIMESTAMP during create/update even after product has been matured for very long time. I will find some other way to do it, Thanks for your feedback. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Is this still a problem with 5.6.3.FINAL ?